# eval doesn't behave the same on React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, eval

I have to interpret some code dynamically in a React Native app (`v0.70.6`). It's something like this:

```
var myVar = 3;
console.log('myVar', myVar);
eval('myVar = 8');
console.log('myVar', myVar);
```

At execution, the behavior is wrong : I'm getting `myVar 3` twice.

When testing the same code via the Node CLI or simply a browser console, I get the correct result : `myVar 3` and `myVar 8`.

Has the `eval` implementation changed in React Native ? It was working previously but I couldn't find anything that has changed in the changelogs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not directly related to React Native, it's related to [hermes](https://github.com/facebook/hermes/issues/785).

Instead of assigning the variable in `eval`, I switched to using `Function` and returning the value.